# htaccess mod url rewrite not working

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Trying to rewrite former urls to the latter. Rewrite that doesn't work for some reason. How to fix? Thanks.

www.example.com/example-example.html

www.example.com/example-example/

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+-?[a-z]+)/$ /$1.html
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but still doesn't work for some reason. Anything else I should be doing? I have the .htaccess file in my domain directory with the following lines pasted in, but the URL's stay unchanged.

Comment: apache? If yes, check directive `AllowOverride` and set to `All` for your domain configuration

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/?$ $1.html
```

This will silently rewrite a user's request for /example-example/ to an actual file path /example-example.html. No checking is performed to see whether the file path exists, and it will match any request which contains letters and hyphens. If you need more specific constraints, let us know.